# How to use COMMIT in Procedure called by trigger

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

I have the below trigger(mytrg) which calls a procedure(myproc) that will update table2 if any insert in table1. I have "COMMIT" statement in the procedure after the data is updated in table2. But when there is an insert in table1, i get the below error.

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
ORA-06512: at "myschema.myproc", line 63
ORA-06512: at "myschema.mytrg", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'myschema.mytrg'
04092. 00000 -  "cannot %s in a trigger"
*Cause:    A trigger attempted to commit or rollback.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger so it does not commit or rollback.

**Trigger:**                                                                                        
create or replace
trigger mytrg
after insert on table1
for each row
begin
myschema.myproc(:new.ID, :new.NAME, :new.TYPE_CODE, :new.LANGUAGE);
end;
```

Need to know how to commit the update.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not have a COMMIT inside a trigger. Your UPDATE will be committed as soon as the INSERT to the table1 is committed.

But to achieve what you want you can use an autonomous transaction. For example,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytrg
AFTER INSERT ON table1 FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE    
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;    
BEGIN    
   myschema.myproc(:new.ID, :new.NAME, :new.TYPE_CODE, :new.LANGUAGE);    
   COMMIT;    
END;
```