# Executing a Procedure inside trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I am trying to call a procedure , when a trigger is fired.
When i execute the following trigger, it works fine

```
create or replace
TRIGGER EVAL_CHANGE_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON t_agents_vs_tl for each row
DECLARE

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bkp_t_agents_vs_tl (agent_name, active_status)
    VALUES ('1', 'active');
END
```

but when i try to call a procedure inside this trigger as below

```
create or replace
TRIGGER EVAL_CHANGE_TRIGGER
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON t_agents_vs_tl for each row
DECLARE

BEGIN

pro_failed_procedure();
  INSERT INTO bkp_t_agents_vs_tl (agent_name, active_status)
    VALUES ('1', 'active');
END
```

I get the following error: *Cannot Commit inside a trigger. Rewrite trigger*

I am not able to identify the error . Please help

Comment: The procedure `pro_failed_procedure` is executing an implicit or explicit `COMMIT`, either directly or in one of the subprograms it itself calls. You will need to trace the call tree to find where this `COMMIT` is and ensure it is not executed when the procedure is called from the trigger.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23295294/how-to-use-commit-in-procedure-called-by-trigger) could help if you are doing a commit inside the proc.

Comment: There are few things i want to talk about. First: learn how to format your posts, because they might be found unreadable. Second: you put both `oracle` and `sql-server` tags - don't put tags that are unrelated to your problem. Third: if your procedure use commit statements, then i suggest you to rewrite it with `pragma autonomous_transaction`.

Comment: Looks like pro_failed_procedure() SP having a transaction within it. Remove commit/rollback transaction within it.

Comment: Firstly, `Pragma autonomous_transaction` inside a trigger is mostly used only for specific purpose, like sending an email to notify irrespective of the failed transactions. Beware what you do in production. Secondly, `COMMIT' inside a PL/SQL block is mostly unnecessary. Because the caller would be refrained from an `ATOMIC` transaction.